# Workflow Email - Lookup email address

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, send-email

I used SPD2010 to create a generic "send email" notification that cc's to a shared mailbox and has a "to" that directs to a personal mailbox on the same network. I'm using a lookup in the list to return the personal mailbox value (they're stored on the list as plain text "mailto:...").

The emails go to the static mailbox and show the correct personal mailbox, but they aren't showing up in the personal mailbox. I'm honestly unsure why it shows the correct address, but doesn't ever show up. Anyone have a better workaround than the one I describe above?

Comment: Just to make sure I understood, the emails getting to the static mailbox has the correct To value and it looks like it's resolved? Have you checked junk mail?  Is there a reason you're you storing the email addresses as plain text? Are you not connected to AD?

Comment: Yes, that's right. They look resolved, but never show up. I've checked the junk mail. I am connected to the AD, but the scenario is this: salesperson adds new sales opportunity to list. SharePoint looks at the salesperson name and performs a lookup and returns the correct coordinator email address from a separate list. They are linked as plain text because SP doesn't allow links/hyperlinks as a lookup option and I don't know how to pull the correct info otherwise.

Comment: Does it work if the To is an external address?

Comment: No, they're part of the same network.

Comment: I meant that I would trouble-shoot by trying it with an external address.... like my gmail account.